# How to put $last ngRepeat result out of href?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-switch, angularjs-ng-if

Is there any option to put $last ng-repeat result like this `<li class="active">Four</li>` instead of `<li><a href="#">Four</a></li>` ?
I have been trying with `ng-if` but unfortunately it did not give good solution yet :(

DEMO: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdvVRe

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('testController', function($scope) {
  $scope.mymenu = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
});
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="testController" class="container">
    <strong>Expecting</strong>
    <br />
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      <li class="active">Four</li>
    </ol>
    <hr />
    <strong>Current result</strong>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li ng-repeat="menu in mymenu"><a href="#">{{menu}}</a></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<li ng-repeat="menu in mymenu" ng-class="{active: $last}">
    <a ng-if="!$last" href="#">{{menu}}</a>
    <span ng-if="$last">{{menu}}</span>
</li>
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/domYZL

Comment: I didn't know the about `$last`, so I was using all kinds of expressions to find the last item in list. Thanks! :D